# React.js create loop through Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, reactjs

I'm trying to display a Table of 10 Players. I get the data from via ajax and pass it as props to my Child.

```
var CurrentGame = React.createClass({

  // get game info
  loadGameData: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/example.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error('#GET Error', status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {data: []};
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadGameData();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="CurrentGame">
        <h1> Current Game Information</h1>
        <PlayerList data={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Now I need a List Component to Render the Players:

```
var PlayerList = React.createClass({


  render: function() {

    // This prints the correct data
    console.log(this.props.data);

    return (
      <ul className="PlayerList">
        // I'm the Player List {this.props.data}
        // <Player author="The Mini John" />

        {
          this.props.data.participants.map(function(player) {
            return <li key={player}>{player}</li>
          })
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
});
```

Which gives me a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

I'm kind of unsure what is happening, my console log displays the correct data but somehow I can't access it in the return.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In `CurrentGame` component you need to change initial state because you are trying use loop for `participants` but this property is `undefined` that's why you get error.,

```
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
       data: {
          participants: [] 
       }
    };
},
```

also, as `player` in `.map` is `Object` you should get properties from it

```
this.props.data.participants.map(function(player) {
   return <li key={player.championId}>{player.summonerName}</li>
   // -------------------^^^^^^^^^^^---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/vdw27xpf/2/)

Comment: Could you add onClick event for each list item and pass the list item to the function? print the data in the function?

Answer (score 17):

As @Alexander solves, the issue is one of async data load - you're rendering immediately and you will not have participants loaded until the async ajax call resolves and populates `data` with `participants`.

The alternative to the solution they provided would be to prevent render until participants exist, something like this:

```
    render: function() {
        if (!this.props.data.participants) {
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <ul className="PlayerList">
            // I'm the Player List {this.props.data}
            // <Player author="The Mini John" />
            {
                this.props.data.participants.map(function(player) {
                    return <li key={player}>{player}</li>
                })
            }
            </ul>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do conditional check before doing map like

```
{Array.isArray(this.props.data.participants) && this.props.data.participants.map(function(player) {
   return <li key={player.championId}>{player.summonerName}</li>
   })
}
```

Now a days .map can be done in two different ways but still the conditional check is required like

.map with return

```
{Array.isArray(this.props.data.participants) && this.props.data.participants.map(player => {
   return <li key={player.championId}>{player.summonerName}</li>
 })
}
```

.map without return

```
{Array.isArray(this.props.data.participants) && this.props.data.participants.map(player => (
   return <li key={player.championId}>{player.summonerName}</li>
 ))
}
```

both the above functionalities does the same