# Iterate loop over state object with an array key in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a function `getBar()` returning an object like:

```
{
  foo: 'value',
  array: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

Here's my React component calling the above function i.e. `getBar()`:

```
class foo extends Component {

  state = {
    bar: {}
  };    
  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({
      bar : getBar()
    });
  }
  render() {
    {this.state.bar.array.map((value, i) => <div class="row" key={i}>{value}</div>)}
  }
}
```

It always gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` error. [Exploring similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28320488/3151337), I came to know I will have to declare an empty state array which I did in different ways but none worked. Can anybody please give me an appropriate answer preferably with complete logic.

I tried another way of declaring the state array to a `const` in `render()` but didn't get successful results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this is actually something to do with your [component's lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle)

The problem is that your `render` method runs before the `componentDidMount` method. So the first time your component renders your state looks like this:

```
{
  bar: {},
}
```

So no array property on bar, which means you cannot map over it (which is why you get errors ). Instead you could use the `componentWillMount` method, to set the state before the render method runs, or you could do a check on array being set before mapping over it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I was trying different tweaks since an hour but using `componentWillMount` worked flawlessly.