# How to print props data in react component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

This is my react component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { promised } from 'q';

const Trending = (props) => {
    console.log(props.data);


    return (
        <div>
        //code to print

        </div>
    ) 
}

export default Trending;
```

I am getting my data in my console log.

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
db_frequency: 17
db_keyword: "modi"
__proto__: Object
1: {db_keyword: "gandhi", db_frequency: 14}
2: {db_keyword: "ipl", db_frequency: 10}
3: {db_keyword: "election", db_frequency: 18}
4: {db_keyword: "vote", db_frequency: 7}
5: {db_keyword: "upsc", db_frequency: 11}
6: {db_keyword: "dhoni", db_frequency: 6}
7: {db_keyword: "ranveer", db_frequency: 7}
8: {db_keyword: "pollution", db_frequency: 2}
9: {db_keyword: "unemployment", db_frequency: 1}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I want to print all the db_keyword and db_frequency in my html page. Kindly help to print the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js create loop through Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320438/react-js-create-loop-through-array). Also, [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map` like so:

```
return (
    <div>
        <ul>
            {props.data.map(({ db_keyword, db_frequency }, index) => <li key={index}>Keyword: {db_keyword}, Frequency: {db_frequency}</li>)}
        </ul>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: you forgot to add key prop.

Comment: @julekgwa What do you mean?

Comment: Thank you so much all of you. @JackBashford code is working.

Comment: @JackBashford react is going to throw `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.` warning in the console.

Comment: A “key” is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements. Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: Ok@julekgwa, so would I fix that by adding `key={index}` where `index` is the index?

Comment: @JackBashford yes, you should add that key.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to loop over items, and return the element you want, e.g. `<div>`, `<h1>` etc.

```
return (<div>
  <ul>
    props.data.map((item, i) => <li key={i}>{`Keyword: ${item.db_keyword}, Frequency: ${item.db_frequency}`}</li>)
  </ul>
</div>
```